# TortoiseSVN splash screen continually pops up

Tags: tortoisesvn

I installed a slightly older version of TortoiseSVN - 1.8.12 Bld 26645.  The splash screen continually pops up.  When I click 'OK' it pops up again.

Answer (score 1):

You may to run somehow broken TortoiseProc in command-line by hand, which, for `:about` [command](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)

> :about    Shows the about dialog. This is also shown if no command is given